# JLabel scrolling text

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I need to make a piece of text that scrolls along the page by taking each letter and moving it from one jlabel to the next. This is my code so far. It needs a delay because its too fast but it seem to crash when the string has finished. Any help would be appreciated?.

```
package Lab4;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Scroll extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
final int scrollNumber = 10;
JTextField inputTextField = new JTextField(10);
JLabel[] output = new JLabel[scrollNumber];
JLabel text = new JLabel("Enter text and press Return",
        SwingConstants.CENTER);

public Scroll() {

    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    JPanel row1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 10));

    output[0] = new JLabel();
    output[1] = new JLabel();
    output[2] = new JLabel();
    output[3] = new JLabel();
    output[4] = new JLabel();
    output[5] = new JLabel();
    output[6] = new JLabel();
    output[7] = new JLabel();
    output[8] = new JLabel();
    output[9] = new JLabel();

    row1.add(output[9]);
    row1.add(output[8]);
    row1.add(output[7]);
    row1.add(output[6]);
    row1.add(output[5]);
    row1.add(output[4]);
    row1.add(output[3]);
    row1.add(output[2]);
    row1.add(output[1]);
    row1.add(output[0]);

    add(row1);
    JPanel row2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    row2.add(text);
    row2.add(inputTextField);
    add(row2);

    inputTextField.addActionListener(this);

}

public void shift() {

    output[9].setText(output[8].getText());
    output[8].setText(output[7].getText());
    output[7].setText(output[6].getText());
    output[6].setText(output[5].getText());
    output[5].setText(output[4].getText());
    output[4].setText(output[3].getText());
    output[3].setText(output[2].getText());
    output[2].setText(output[1].getText());
    output[1].setText(output[0].getText());

}

public void run(String input) {
    int length = input.length();
    int i = 0;

    while (true) {

        if (output[0] != null) {
            output[0].setText(input.substring(i, i + 1));

        } else {
            output[0].setText("");
        }
        i = i + 1;
        System.out.println("0" + output[0].getText());
        System.out.println("1" + output[1].getText());
        System.out.println("2" + output[2].getText());
        System.out.println("3" + output[3].getText());
        System.out.println("4" + output[4].getText());
        System.out.println("5" + output[5].getText());
        System.out.println("6" + output[6].getText());
        System.out.println("7" + output[7].getText());
        System.out.println("8" + output[8].getText());
        System.out.println("9" + output[9].getText());
        shift();

    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == inputTextField) {

        String j = inputTextField.getText();
        run("abcdef");
        System.out.println(j);
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all. Yes your application crashes. Technically its an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` that you get when invoking `input.substring(i, i + 1)` in your `run` method. You increment `i` in an infinite loop without resitriction. And so it gets higher than your string length with the result that `substring` then throws that exception.
So first fix is a restriction when incrementing your index.

```
[...]
i = i + 1;
if(i > length - 1)
    i = 0;
```

Next fix should be a delay. But thats not as easy as it sounds. You should start learning how `Threads` work in Java because you will need to start one. Thats because you should never send your main Thread to sleep or your GUI will get unresponsible. So I will give you one simple solution and remind you to learn how Threads work.
So remove your `run` method and change your `actionPerformed` method like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == inputTextField) {

        String j = inputTextField.getText();
        // run("abcdef");
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int length = j.length();
                int i = 0;
                while (true) {
                    if (output[0] != null) {
                        output[0].setText(j.substring(i, i + 1));
                    } else {
                        output[0].setText("");
                    }
                    i = i + 1;
                    if(i > length - 1)
                        i = 0;                                              
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500); // your delay in ms
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                       
                    shift();                        
                }               
            }           
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but last question, how do i make it only run by once?

Comment: You will need a condition for your `while` loop so it could end when finish. Something like: `int runs = 0; while (runs++ < ((length - 1) + output.length)) { [...] }`.